# GCloud Function gives 'Access denied' to a Storage Bucket object

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

A deployed Google Cloud Function is supposed to read data from a Storage Bucket. Both are in the same project (Function and the Bucket).
The function has a Bucket object 'create trigger', which works fine. But when it comes to reading the object's content an Access Denied message comes up (as found in logs).

Which seems like a permission problem. Although the Function is using a default Service Account created by GCP with an Editor role, which as I found in docs, is supposed to have no problem with permissions for reading the Storage Bucket.

Which seems like I'm missing something really important.

There is one more thing to notice: there was an accident a few days ago, where some project parts were removed by an accident, after that the whole project was renewed to its a previous state. And this was the time when strange things, like this, started to happen. Before this accident, we had no problems with functions access permissions...

Function run log follows:

```
//Real values ommitted
Function execution started update-from-bucket 
update-from-bucket triggered by: Event XXX, Event Type: google.storage.object.finalize, Bucket: BUCKET_NAME, File: FILE_NAME update-from-bucket 
update-from-bucket submitted: Job PROJECT_NAME finished. 
update-from-bucket [ { reason: 'accessDenied', update-from-bucket 
update-from-bucket 'Access Denied: File gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME: Access Denied' } ]
```

Comment: Could you edit your question with the errors you are seeing in the logs? I'd be also helpful if you could share which specific permissions this SA has

Comment: Log included, the SA has an Editor role with GC default settings including storage.buckets.create, storage.buckets.delete, storage.buckets.list permissions.

Comment: Hello, I was not able to reproduce this issue, and according to your description, this might be an issue originated by the "recovery" of the removal incident. In order to further troubleshoot this, we'll require more information about your project, and for that I recommend opening a new issue here -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491168

Comment: The issue was created

Comment: Hello again @klimpond, could you give me the id of the PIT ticket?. In this case I'm using the private PIT ticket so you can share your project info with me without leaking sensitive information, however, have in mind that Issue Tracker is meant to be used for issues that can be reproducible (which is not your case). If you have GCP support, then the best channel you can use for this issue is a Support Case (https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/procedures). If you don't count with GCP support then we can continue over the PIT case.

Comment: Hello, @Mayeru the ID is 141918366.

Comment: Excellent, we can continue the troubleshooting over there, and will come back here once the solution is found.

Comment: Agreed, I'm really curios about solving this.